# How to pass array of argument to batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am having batch file called Formalbuild.bat ,It will take parameter name called componentName.

For ex. I will build the different components like below.

```
    Formalbuild.bat ServiceComponent
    Formalbuild.bat DatamodelComponent
    Formalbuild.bat 
                ...
                ...
    Formalbuild.bat SomeXYZComponent
```

Is it possible to create array of component name and pass one by one component to batch file to do build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As only the component name changes, you could use a `for` loop or even better a `for/f` loop.

```
FOR %%C in (ServiceComponent DatamodelComponent SomeXYZComponent ) do (
    call Formalbuild.bat %%C
)
```

If the list of components is long you could also split them into multiple lines

```
FOR %%C in (ServiceComponent 
DatamodelComponent
component3
...
component_n
SomeXYZComponent ) do (
    call Formalbuild.bat %%C
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a simple counting loop suffice?

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,N) do call Formalbuild.bat Component%%x
```

Replace `N` by the proper number there.

If you want to run this on the command line, then use

```
for /l %x in (1,1,N) do Formalbuild.bat Component%x
```

And since there is a PowerShell tag in your question (although you never mention it):

```
1..N | %{Formalbuild.bat Component$_}
```

Replace N by the actual value, as usual.

Comment: I have updated my question as it was giving assumption that i can loop through by changing last digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%a in (
    Component1
    Component2
    Component3
    ...
    ...
    ComponentN) do call :FormalBuild %%a

:FormalBuild
set THING_TO_BUILD=%1
REM call your build stuff here with %THING_TO_BUILD% identifying what you are building
```